# is it possible to make loop unroll in F# (in .net at all)?

Tags: .net, f#

so what I mean by loop unroll is like

```
Write "Hello" |> Repeat 5
```

->>>

```
Write "Hello"
Write "Hello"
Write "Hello"
Write "Hello"
Write "Hello"
```

as far as I know that is some optimization and I just interesting if that possible on .NET

By the way - Simply why I must use for i in [0..4] do ... if I don't really not this [0..4] and I don't really need this i ...

Comment: you want to type the above and have the result below in your code?

Comment: @Dan Andrews No I want a language feature alike Repeat that will generate same IL N times.

Comment: No such thing exists. Try "for 1 to n".

Comment: IL isn't meant to include any optimalizations. Optimalizations are made when translating from IL to native in JIT.

Comment: according last comments - So it's looking like I can't do it without using for - that's sad. I've got another off-topic question : Why do you answer as a comments ?

Comment: @nCdy: why do you ask questions in a comments? ;-)

Comment: @zerkms because comments is like a dialog so I answering on previous comments. Not adding something new to main question for other people.

Comment: @nCdy re "why do you ask questions in a comments" - because they aren't really *answers* to the question...  things like asides, requests for more info, etc are best presented as comments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The F# language doesn't directly support this form of meta-programming. What you're asking for is usually called *multi-stage programming* and there are ML-based languages that support it (search for example for MetaML). In these languages, you can manipulate with compiled code and (e.g.) unroll loops.

A limited form of this can be done in F# using quotations. It isn't very practical though, because F# quotation compiler generates slower code (so it definitely doesn't work as an optimization).

However, just for a curiosity, here is how to achieve this using quotations and quotation compiler from F# PowerPack:

```
#r @"FSharp.PowerPack.Linq.dll"
open Microsoft.FSharp.Linq.QuotationEvaluation

// Generate quotation that contains 5 prints followed by expression that returns unit
let unrolled = [ 1 .. 5 ] |> List.fold (fun expr _ -> 
    <@ printfn "Hello"; %expr @>) <@ () @>

// Compile the function once & run it two times
let f = unrolled.Compile()
f()
f()
```

... as I mentioned, this isn't useful as an optimization, because the `Compile` method produces slow code, but it is useful in some other scenarios.

Comment: Does the Compile method actually produce slow code, or did you mean to say that the Compile method in itself is slow?

Comment: @Robert: It actually produces slow code. It uses expression trees from C# 3, so it uses quite limited target langauge. For example, `printf "a"; printf "b"` is compiled as (in C# syntax) `Helpers.Sequence(() => printf("a"), () => printf "b");`

Answer (score 5):

You may write `for _ in 0..4` to indicate that you don't need the value of the loop variable.

Doing something like loop unrolling on the F# language level would require support for macros. In languages like Lisp or Clojure you could do that. But usually it is better to let the compiler or the runtime worry about that.

On the IL level, you could implement things like loop unrolling using classes of the `System.Reflection.Emit` namespace (or using a library like Cecil for that).

Comment: interesting if that is real for Nemerle macros

Answer (score 3):

You can't do without 'for', but you can abstract it in your own function

```
let Write msg = 
    fun () -> printfn msg

let Repeat n f = 
    for _ in 1..n do
        f() 

Write "Hello" |> Repeat  5
```